# Is any metric space, constructed from real numbers with a usual metric, open?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

For example, I am trying to determine whether a metric space $X = (A, d)$, where $A = [0,1]$ and d is a usual metric, is open. Using the same logic as for proving openness of any set in a discrete metric space, it seems that X is open. If I am right, is it always true that any metric space, consisting of a set of reals and a usual metric, is open?

Comment: Did you try to apply the definition of open set?

Comment: In any topology, the universe and empty set are always open.

Comment: Yes, I applied definition and sort of proved that any whole metric space is open and was a bit confused. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any metric induces a topology and in any topological space the universe, and empty set, are both open, and they are both closed too.